# Sql как вычислить количество элементов с нужным параметром

Tags: sql

```
select num from job_history where count(num) = 1
```

мне нужно выбрать из таблицы такие номера, которые в таблице в единственном экземпляре.

Answer (score 1):

```
select num from job_history group by num having count(*) = 1;
```